# Problema con la renderización de componentes en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas el problema que tengo es que necesito saber como poder renderizar un componente en el momento que un usuario haga determinada acción, en este caso estoy trabajando con React Beautiful DND, que es una librería para hacer drags & drops, lo que quiero conseguir es que a la hora que el usuario haga el drop, en el método que llama esa acción poder renderizar un componente, en este caso sacar un modal para pedir más información al usuario.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow! Podrías agregar lo que has intentado? Algo de código es útil para poder ayudarte, te invito a leer: [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías agregar un addEventListenr "drop" y un estado "showComponent" como valor inicial "false" y cambiarlo a true cuando el evento "drop" sea disparado.

```
const Comp = () => {
   const elRef = useRef(null)
   const [ showComponent, setShowComponent ] = useState(false)
   useEffect(()=>{
      const el = elRef.current
      const handleDrop = e => {
         e.preventDefault()
         setShowComponent(true)
      }
      el.addEvenetListener('drop', handleDrop)
      return () => el.removeEventListener('drop', handleDrop)
   }, [])
   return (
   <div>
      <div ref={elRef}>
         Drop me!
      </div>
      { showComponent && <MiComponenteAparece /> }
   </div>
   )
}
```

Las demás consideraciones son propias de las API's nativas de drag and drop y vanilla. Pero esta idea en sí debería funcionar por tu pregunta de "cómo" con "React". Sé que no mencioné sobre React Beautiful DND pero seguro que en su documentación debe haber una formar de usar esos eventos o sino tocaría manejarlo propiamente.

Espero que te ayude en algo. Saludos.